# Microsoft Graph-Delete planner task-Resource not found for the segment (ETag)?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-planner

I am trying to delete Planner task using Microsoft graph according to instruction on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/plannertask-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

GET works, DELETE does not.

Request should look like:

```
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/tasks/{id}
If-Match: W/"JzEtVGFzayAgQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAWCc="
```

In my case, it is:

```
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/tasks/nWf2j63qnk69r69ZdK7135cAMVlSIf-Match:W/"JzEtVGFzayAgQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAWCc="
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
GET
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/tasks/nWf2j63qnk69r69ZdK7135cAMVlS

{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#planner/tasks/$entity",
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"JzEtVGFzayAgQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAWCc=\"",
    ...
    "id": "nWf2j63qnk69r69ZdK7135cAMVlS",
    ...


{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Resource not found for the segment '\"JzEtVGFzayAgQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAWCc=\"'.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "58d3c417-6474-422c-912d-e6fdaae856c3",
            "date": "2019-09-06T23:47:35"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are trying to pass `If-Match` via request url:

```
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/tasks/nWf2j63qnk69r69ZdK7135cAMVlSIf-Match:W/"JzEtVGFzayAgQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAWCc="
                                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

while it is expected to be provided via request headers, like this:

```
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/tasks/{id}
Headers: 
   If-Match: W/"JzEtVGFzayAgQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAWCc="
   Authorization: Bearer <access-token>
```

**Graph Explorer example**

[image]